# SQL server sub queries vs. table joins

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've read that table joins are usually more efficient over sub queries, is this true? Will SQL Server 2005 and/or 2008 convert the sub query to a table join if it thinks it would be better?(Considering it uses a declarative language rather than an imperative one).

Regardless of the size of the tables i'm working with, I would like to get in the habit of doing it the best way. That means that if most of the time SQL Server will probably convert my code to a Join, I will just save it from having to do the work.

Note: Sub queries seem to be less code to write, but I don't think joins are any harder to visualize than writing a sub query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be best to check the execution plan for individual cases. This will clue you in on its internal operation. Try the query a few different ways and analyze the execution plans.

Comment: I think that is a good idea. It sounds like from your response that it is not necessarily bad to do it either way.

Comment: @nick: The truth is that it depends on data, table structure, and expected output.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks, I'll analyze the execution plans. P.s. nice name.

Comment: indeed always best to check the plans, although I have generally found derived tables or sub queries to be less efficient than putting the data in a table of some sort first, particularly when your handling 10s of millions of rows.